# how do i spawn a process in perl without it becoming defunct or a zombie when the parent exits?

Tags: perl, process, zombie-process

I have a perl script which i'd like to spawn a process. It can take a while and most times the parent script will exit. How do I spawn this process so that when the parent is gone it wont turn into a zombie or a defunct process when its done?

edit: I think ive found two methods. Hopefully someone could tell me which one is more appropriate?

1. setting $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
2. use POSIX 'setsid';

edit: The spawned process is also going to be another perl script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A process becomes as zombie when it exits and before its parent process picks up its status with `wait()`.  When one process forks another and then exits, the child becomes a parent of pid 1 (classically "init") which immediately reaps the process state.  So usually the problem is the reverse of what you describe:  The child becomes a zombie (since the parent was not written to deal with `SIGCHLD` and call `wait()`) but when the parent exits the zombie is inherited by `init` and immediately reaped.  In fact, the usual solution to decouple a child process fully from its parent ("daemonize") involves intentionally forking and having the intermediate process exit so that the daemon is immediately a child of `init`.

Edit:  If you're in shell and want to achieve this effect, try `(subprocess &)`.  The parenthesis create a subshell which executes `subprocess` in the background and then immeidately exits.

Comment: so your saying I should use setsid? Is there a difference between the two methods I listed?

Comment: @Incognito, He said you can't get zombies after the parent is gone. Neither of the two methods will get rid of zombies that don't exist.